# Javascript - Como calcular média de dados em um array com vários objetos e retornar em outro array

Tags: javascript, algoritmo

Tendo um array `notasAlunos`, como exemplo reduzido:

```
notasAlunos = [
 { matricula: "117", nome: "Joao", materia: "x1", nota: 78 },
 { matricula: "117" nome: "Joao", materia: "x8", nota: 80 },
 { matricula: "117", nome: "Joao", materia: "y5", nota: 48 },
 { matricula: "119", nome: "Pedro", materia: "w2", nota: 69 },
 { matricula: "119" nome: "Pedro", materia: "x2", nota: 90 },
 { matricula: "132", nome: "Joana" materia: "v3", nota: 77 },
 { matricula:"132" nome: "Joana", materia: "w2", nota: 76 } 
]
```

Gostaria de obter como retorno o seguinte `array`:

```
MediaNotasAluno = [
 { matricula: "117", media: 68,66},
 { matricula: "119", media: 79,50},
 { matricula "132", media: 76,50} 
]
```

Tentativa de código:

```
var MediaNotasAluno = []
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < notasAlunos.length; i++) {
        total += notasAlunos[i].nota
        var avg = total / notasAlunos[i].nota.lenght
        MediaNotasAluno.push({notasAlunos.matricula, avg})
    }
```

Comment: Tentou fazer algum código? qual foi o seu esforço?

Comment: Tentei, mas sem sucesso, veja um exemplo: var mediaNotasAlunos = []
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < notasAlunos.length; i++) {
            total += notasAlunos[i].nota
            var avg = total / notasAlunos[i].nota.lenght
            mediaNotasAlunos.push({notasAlunos[.matricula, avg})
        }

Comment: Pode editar a pergunta e inserir o código que tentou fazer nela. Mas pelo array de objetos no exemplo postado, não vai nem rodar a sua tentativa, pq, a propriedade **nome** e a propriedade **materia** possui caracteres inválidos. Teriam que ser **`string`**.

Comment: todos os campos são string, exceto nota que é int. Eu não havia postado corretamente. Obrigado.

Comment: Ajudou muito, as duas respostas funcionam perfeitamente. Obrigado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema é que você está somando as notas de todos os alunos, e além disso está dividindo pela quantidade de notas no meio do *loop* (o que não faz sentido, pois para calcular a média você só deve dividir depois de somar todas as notas - ou seja, deveria ser fora do `for`, não dentro dele).

E se você quer a média de cada aluno, tem que calcular vários totais diferentes (um para cada matrícula). E a divisão só pode ser feita no final, depois que você somou tudo (e não dentro do `for`).

Uma forma de fazer é guardar os totais de cada aluno e a respectiva quantidade de notas em um objeto. Depois você calcula a média para cada um:

```js
let notasAlunos = [
 { matricula: "117", nome: "Joao", materia: "x1", nota: 78 },
 { matricula: "117", nome: "Joao", materia: "x8", nota: 80 },
 { matricula: "117", nome: "Joao", materia: "y5", nota: 48 },
 { matricula: "119", nome: "Pedro", materia: "w2", nota: 69 },
 { matricula: "119", nome: "Pedro", materia: "x2", nota: 90 },
 { matricula: "132", nome: "Joana", materia: "v3", nota: 77 },
 { matricula: "132", nome: "Joana", materia: "w2", nota: 76 } 
];

// calcula a soma das notas de cada aluno (e também a quantidade de notas para cada um)
let MediaNotasAluno = {};
for (let notaAluno of notasAlunos) {
    // se ainda não tem registro para esta matrícula, cria um novo 
    if (! MediaNotasAluno[notaAluno.matricula]) {
        MediaNotasAluno[notaAluno.matricula] = {
            'matricula': notaAluno.matricula, 'total': 0, 'qtd': 0
        };
    }
    // atualiza o total e a quantidade de notas
    MediaNotasAluno[notaAluno.matricula].total += notaAluno.nota;
    MediaNotasAluno[notaAluno.matricula].qtd++;
}

// tendo o total e a quantidade, calcula a média para cada um
// cria um array com os valores
MediaNotasAluno = Object.values(MediaNotasAluno);
for (let m of MediaNotasAluno) {
    m.media = m.total / m.qtd;
    // apaga a quantidade e o total, pois não preciso mais
    delete m['qtd'];
    delete m['total'];
}
console.log(MediaNotasAluno);
```

No primeiro `for` eu crio um objeto contendo as matrículas, e para cada uma eu vou somando as notas e atualizando a quantidade de notas. Depois deste primeiro *loop*, o objeto estará assim:

```
{
  '117': { matricula: '117', total: 206, qtd: 3 },
  '119': { matricula: '119', total: 159, qtd: 2 },
  '132': { matricula: '132', total: 153, qtd: 2 }
}
```

Mas como você quer um array, basta pegar os valores do objeto, usando [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).

Depois, no segundo `for` eu uso o total e a quantidade para calcular a média (e em seguida, apago o total e a quantidade, pois não vou precisar mais). O resultado será:

```
[
  { matricula: '117', media: 68.66666666666667 },
  { matricula: '119', media: 79.5 },
  { matricula: '132', media: 76.5 }
]
```

---

Se você quer arredondar os valores para ter apenas duas casas decimais, pode trocar o cálculo para:

```
for (let m of MediaNotasAluno) {
    m.media = Math.floor(100 * m.total / m.qtd) / 100;
    delete m['qtd'];
    delete m['total'];
}
```

Assim a primeira média será `68.66`.

Answer (score 3):

Dá pra fazer assim:

```js
const notasAlunos = [
 { matricula: "117", nome: "Joao", materia: "x1", nota: 78 },
 { matricula: "117", nome: "Joao", materia: "x8", nota: 80 },
 { matricula: "117", nome: "Joao", materia: "y5", nota: 48 },
 { matricula: "119", nome: "Pedro", materia: "w2", nota: 69 },
 { matricula: "119", nome: "Pedro", materia: "x2", nota: 90 },
 { matricula: "132", nome: "Joana", materia: "v3", nota: 77 },
 { matricula:"132", nome: "Joana", materia: "w2", nota: 76 } 
]

const acum = [];

notasAlunos.forEach(aluno => {
  const match = acum.find(media => media.matricula === aluno.matricula);
  if (match) {
    match.soma += aluno.nota
    match.notas++;
  } else {
    aluno.soma = aluno.nota
    aluno.notas = 1;
    acum.push(aluno)
  }
});

const medias = [].map.call(acum, i => ({matricula: i.matricula, media: i.soma / i.notas}))

console.log(medias);
```

Use um array para registrar a quantidade de notas e a soma total.

Depois gere o array com a média de cada aluno (soma/qtd).